# Ruby's send method with block variable interpolation

Tags: ruby, send, interpolation

I'm a newb working through some Ruby tutorials and am stumped on the use of the `send` method below. I can see the send method is reading the value of the attribute iterator over, but the Ruby documentation states the send method takes a method prepended with a colon. So, my confusion lies in *how* the send method below is interpolating the attribute variable being iterated over.

```
module FormatAttributes
  def formats(*attributes)
    @format_attribute = attributes
  end

  def format_attributes
    @format_attributes
  end
end

module Formatter
  def display
    self.class.format_attributes.each do |attribute|
      puts "[#{attribute.to_s.upcase}] #{send(attribute)}"
    end
  end
end

class Resume
  extend FormatAttributes
  include Formatter
  attr_accessor :name, :phone_number, :email, :experience
  formats :name, :phone_number, :email, :experience
end
```

Comment: `send` can take strings as well, not only symbols. "method prepended with a colon" - that's a symbol, it's very basic ruby concept. So, what exactly is your question again?

Comment: How is #{send(attribute)} interpolated into the individual attribute value?

Comment: `attribute` is attribute name, `send(attribute)` gets value by name, `#{send(attribute)}` inserts it to a string. It's no different than, say, `#{foo}` or `#{10 * 20}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not "invoking the value of the iterator", but instead calling a method with that name. In this case because of the `attr_accessor` declaration, these methods map to properties.

Calling `object.send('method_name')` or `object.send(:method_name)` are equivalent to `object.method_name` in general terms. Likewise, `send(:foo)` and `foo` will call the method `foo` on the context.

Since the `module` declare a method that is later mixed in with an `include`, calling `send` in the module has the effect of calling a method on an instance of the Resume class.

Comment: @tadam, thanks! Being new I was not considering that attr_accessor was turning the properties into methods. Makes perfect sense now.

Comment: `attr_reader` makes a read method (getter), `attr_writer` creates a write method (setter), and `attr_accessor` creates both.

Answer (score 0):

[`send Documentation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send)

here is simplified version of your code,to feed you what's going on:

```
def show
 p "hi"
end

x = "show"
y = :show

"#{send(y)}"   #=> "hi"
"#{send(x)}"   #=> "hi"
```

Comment: Worth noting that `x = :show; "#{send(x)}"` would also work. I think in this case string values are coerced to symbols, so one part of the answer to OP could be "Ruby provides built-in coercion, and that allows the posted code to work"

Comment: @NeilSlater I tried to show him, how send works. That's it. Is any thing fault in my code? correct me. I didn't get you.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. I was just trying to join it up to something I noticed in the OP ("takes a method prepended with a colon")